# Java/Scala: Assign the program/application arguments based on the machine name/ip

Tags: java, scala, system, jvm-arguments

I am writing tests in Java/Scala which need to read some input data. The data location is different for different machines (different application arguments). How can I find out which machine is the current machine from Java? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the class `SystemUtils` from apache commons lang.

This class has some class variables that let you know which is your operating system:

```
    if(SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS)
        System.out.println("It's a Windows OS");
    if(SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS_7)
        System.out.println("It's a Windows 7 OS");
    if(SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS_8)
        System.out.println("It's a Windows 8 OS");
    if(SystemUtils.IS_OS_LINUX)
        System.out.println("It's a Linux OS");
    if(SystemUtils.IS_OS_MAC)
        System.out.println("It's a MAC OS");
```

Comment: What if both my machine are LINUX, they just have different ip-address or machine name? Is this doable? Thanks!